Is there a way to add a page in Astro with docs style rendering of content
I am totally new to UI and Astro project. I am using astrowind (astro framework) theme to modify the website.
I am looking to develop a site which will have pages of content about the site/product and also wanted to include a documentation on a single page with contents rendering when the user clicks a sidebar.
I know there is a separate framework for rendering docs only (docs.astro.com). But is there a way to integrate this together and deploy it as a single site ?
Something like below, with clickable links on left side navbar to new display content on right. May be someone has worked on similar component before.
PS: I have no skill to develop a component, but can try if there are any references.


Perhaps you're looking for https://starlight.astro.build/ ?

Thanks, I thought starlight was a standalone docs page. I went through the documentation and was able to achieve this. Thanks a lot.

So, I was able to integrate starlight with astrowind using the documentation given in the site.
Content from astro.config.ts
integrations: [
tailwind({
  applyBaseStyles: false,
}),
sitemap(),
starlight({
  title: 'Docs',
  tableOfContents: false,
  sidebar: [
    // A single link item labelled “Home”.
    { label: 'Home', link: '/guides' },
    { label: 'Home', link: '/guides/about' },
  ],
}),
mdx(),

Added below in config.ts
export const collections = {
  post: postCollection,
  docs: defineCollection({ schema: docsSchema() }),
};

Then the src/content directory structure,
├── content
│   ├── config.ts
│   ├── docs
│   │   └── guides
│   │       ├── about.mdx
│   │       └── index.mdx
│   └── post
│       ├── astrowind-template-in-depth.mdx

